# extract data to from another column that will not be list

Tags: r

```
        Order ID          Country Region   |   Topreg
-------------------------|-----------------|--------------
CA-2014-AB10015140-41954 |  United States  | Central US
IN-2014-JR162107-41675   |    Australia    |   Oceania
IN-2014-CR127307-41929   |    Australia    |   Oceania
ES-2014-KM1637548-41667  |    Germany      |   Western Europe
SG-2014-RH9495111-41948  |    Senegal      |   Western Africa
IN-2014-JM156557-41818   |    Australia    |   Oceania
IN-2012-TS2134092-41219  |    New Zealand  |   Oceania
IN-2013-MB1808592-41378  |    New Zealand  |   Oceania
CA-2014-AB10015140-41954 |  United States  | Central US
CA-2012-AB10015140-40974 |  United States  | Western US
CA-2012-AB10015140-40974 |  United States  | Western US
ID-2013-AJ107801-41383   |    Afghanistan  |   Southern Asia
```

Hi all, I have this data and I want to extract "Europe" or "Asia" from Region column. I wrote a function below and did a lappy to the new column called "topreg" but I got an error as listed. Can someone help me to advise me what went wrong? the new column "topreg" only contained "Others".

```
funcreg <- function(x){     
  if (grepl("Europe", x)){
  y <- c("Europe")} 
  else if (grepl("Asia", x)) {
    y <- c("Asia")} 
  else {y <- c("Others")}
}

df["topreg"] <- lapply(df$Region, funcreg)
error message:
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "topreg", value = list("Others", "Others",  :
  provided 51290 variables to replace 1 variables
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide a sample of your real data.

Comment: In the example you have shared there is no "Europe" or "Asia" in the `Country Region` column. Also please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `ifelse(grepl("Europe",df$topreg),"Europe",ifelse(grepl("Asia",df$topreg),"Asia","Other"))`

Comment: sorry guys, the data was distorted after i posted. this is the data:

Comment: data seems to be distorted after i posted. the data as list:
Order ID          Country           Region                    Topreg
CA-2014           United States   Central US
ES-2014           Germany           Western Europe   
IN-2014            China                 Eastern Asia

Comment: `lapply` returns a list. Try `unlist(lapply(df$Region, funcreg))` or `sapply(df$Region, funcreg)`

Comment: unlist and sapply also cant work. any idea why my function cannot work?